# ASP.NET Membership controls (can I see inside?)

Tags: asp.net-membership

I am looking at ASP.NET membership controls (2008) and have been dropping them onto web pages to see how it all works. In some ASP.NET starter kit web site examples that I downloaded, I notice that between the asp:control tags I can see all the tags of the constituent parts like the textboxes, labels and buttons etc. However with the membership control that I am using in 2008 I do not see these other tags. Is this because the starter kit examples are from an older version or is it possible to expose these inner tags? It seems that this would make it possible to customize the controls. Thanks

pbmoss@hotmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Let's say if you have added a login control to your project's page, if you click on the smart-tag at top right corner of the control, you will find an option

```
convert to template
```

that will allow you to see the same things that you can see in the starter kit project

i hope this helps

regards